# How to change position of a title in ggplot2 from bottom to top

Tags: ggplot2, position, title

For some reason I get title at the bottom of the plot. How do I change its position to the top?

```
p1=ggplot(data, aes(x=var1, y=var2, color=data$var3, shape=data$var3)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE) +
    labs(title=“Main title”) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-5, 5), 
        labels=c("0.01","0.08","1.0","12.2","148.4")) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="Y axis label", limits=c(0,140)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="none")
p1
```

Comment: I tried ggtitle("text") instead of labs(title="text") with the same result.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Don't use `$`  inside `aes`. Please write it as `color=var3, shape=var3)`. In addition your quotation marks are wrong inside `labs`. try `"` instead of `”`